# Implementing Text-to-Speech (TTS) on Punjabi language is not working

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I am implementing `Text-to-Speech(TTS)` in android on English, Hindi and Punjabi language. 
`TTS` working fine in English and Hindi but it is not working on the Punjabi language.

For the Punjabi language, I used this below code

```
 tts.setLanguage(new Locale("pan"));
 tts.speak(output, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

Comment: Did you check that Punjabi is actually supported by the TTS engine? Not all the world's languages are unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

The TextToSpeech object you create (tts) can use any speech engine.  You are probably using the Google engine.

Different engines have different capabilities.

Usually the engine on a device is either:

1) Samsung speech engine - "com.samsung.SMT"

2) Google speech engine - "com.google.android.tts"

or 3) PICO - "com.svox.pico" ... this one is sometimes used on old devices and Android Studio emulators that don't have the Google APIs.

As a developer, you can choose which engine you want to use by defining it in the constructor's final argument, for example, to use the Samsung engine:

TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech(this, new OnInitListener..., "com.samsung.SMT");

But the user must have your desired engine installed, otherwise it will default to whatever engine they do have installed.

Unfortunately, while Google and/or Samsung will probably support Punjabi in the future, none of the engines mentioned above support Punjabi at the moment, but if the user has the eSpeak engine installed (package name: "com.redzoc.ramees.tts.espeak"), and they have installed the Punjabi language pack, then it *should* work.

It seems the best course of action would be to detect if the user A) wants Punjabi, and B) does *not* have espeak installed (or some other engine that you know of that supports Punjabi), then use an intent/alert dialog to install it.

PS - When creating a Locale and setting the language code, according to the Locale documentation, you should use the two-letter abbreviation, "pa" not "pan".

"...a proper Locale would use a two-letter ISO 639-1 code." - [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#getLanguage()).

"When a language has both an alpha-2 code and an alpha-3 code, the alpha-2 code must be used." - [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Localehttps://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale).

Answer (score 1):

There's a Work Around to support Punjabi Text to speech in android as Google is not supporting it officially now. We have translated punjabi text in hindi and then used the Hindi Text to speech feature to achieve the required behaviour.

To speak ਹਰੀ ਬੱਤੀ ਲਈ ਤਿਆਰ ਹੋ ਜਾਓ ਜੀ text in punjabi, we have to use हरी बत्ती लई त्यार हो जाओ जी text in hindi. Thanks

Comment: How did you achieved this? Punjabi to its corresponding hindi text?

Comment: By translating punjabi text in hindi, we can achieve this.

Comment: In My case, it's not working for Hindi also. it giving me error -2. language not supported.

Comment: @AnkurShinde Hindi is directly supported.. i have implemented this. Let me know in case you want code snippet?

Comment: @inderbagga Thanks. But I checked with the getAvailableLanguages(). In some API level 30 devices provides support to 7 languages deu_Deu, eng_USA, rus_RUS, fra_FRA, ita_ITA, eng_GBR, spa_ESP.  For the API level below 30 Hindi language is supported directly.

Answer (score 0):

Andorid does not have Text to speech for Punjabi enabled yet. In my opinion, you have to use Hear2Read app for Punjabi TTS.